# How to get property value from webpart

Tags: web-part, powershell

I want to get webpart property value using powershell

```
$path="C:\Webparts\MyPart.webpart"
$path

[xml]$xmlPath = Get-Content $path

$myrespath = $xmlPath.data.properties.name.UrlWebPart

$myrespath
```

my webpart has this xml

```
webParts webPart data properties property name
```

Answer (score 2):

If your web part is stored in V3 format (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3`) then the following example demonstrates how to get web part property:

```
$path="c:\Search Box.webpart"

$propertyName = "Title"  #replace to your property name UrlWebPart
[xml]$webPart = Get-Content $path
$property = $webPart.webParts.webPart.data.properties.property | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $propertyName }
$propertyValue = $property.'#text'
$propertyValue
```

Comment: cannot convert value system.xml.xmlement to type system.xml.xmldocument

Comment: i cant help if you will not share web part manifest (MyPart.webpart), the example i have provided works just fine for ootb web part (SearcBox)

Comment: Its a content search webpart a default one